Warnings not coming up during visual studio build, Even after Treat Warnings As Error set to true
I have set Treat Warnings As Error to true in a visual c++ project in visual studio, and warning level is set to 4, but when I buid the project the warnings are not coming up especially compiler error: C4267
eg:
DWORD sidLength = std::size(sidBuffer)

But it shows up as error in the CI/CD pipeline which invokes the MSBuild with some wrapper logic for additional error checking.
What am i missing here?

I get a warning - live - https://godbolt.org/z/8r8jqK5bG .  Can you scan the codebase for #pragma warnings to see if the warning is being disabled.

Are you sure your settings are for all project configurations? E.g., maybe you set "warnings as errors" for Release but building Debug.

Changing your code to DWORD sidLength { std::size(foo) }; produces a hard error - live - https://godbolt.org/z/b7W1M3aed as narrowing conversion are not allowed here.

@Eugene, it is set for all configurations and platforms.

@RichardCritten, there are #pragma warnings with push and pop for specific windows header files but none specifically targeting this.

Warnings can also be disabled in the project settings > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Advanced > Disable Specific Warnings

Also check Configuration Properties > C/C++ Command Line.   For any settings that have unexpectedly appeared there.  Individual files can also have their project properties overridden so check the properties for the file in question.
